# How does a cyclization occur with a carboxylic acid and (CF3CO)2O?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis, carbonyl-compounds

The product of the reaction below is unsaturated, bicyclic ketone, but I'm confused as to how (CF3CO)2O reacts with it to cause the cyclization. There is no base involved so I don't know how the carbon delta to the carboxylic acid attacks it. What is the mechanism? [image]

Comment: The "base" or rather nucleophile is the alkene and the electrophile is the mixed anhydride. There are 4 degrees of unsaturation. Take it from there! You are capable of solving this based on our previous discussions.

Comment: @user55119 so the carboxylic acid attacks the anhydride to make its own mixed anhydride, and then the triflate part of the anhydride is eliminated by add-elim through the alkene? Then elimination to form a new alkene happens?

Comment: You have the mixed anhydride correct. Use the alkene as a nucleophile and lose trifluoroacetate wich you can use to deprotonate the tertiary cation via an E1 process.

Comment: BTW: Triflate is triflluoromethane sulfonate, F3CSO2.

Comment: Trifluoroacetate in mixed anhydride is a good leaving group. Alkene attack on carbonyl to make bicyclic system leave stable tertiary carbocation.